# Go through specific Webpages and Export Information from each jsf Webpage to Excel

Tags: jquery, html, excel, parsing, jsf

Is something like this possible:

## Squence of events

#### Load this Page:

> ...Deutsch/5/proxy/dkv/Bundesland/Nordrhein-Westfalen.jsf

#### Get the Session ID and save it

#### Load this page with session ID

> ...Deutsch/5/proxy/dkv/search/results/show/1/name/asc.jsf;jsessionid=
>   -- ID --

#### Find the last site (Maximum is 99)

> ...Deutsch/5/proxy/dkv/search/results/show/99/name/asc.jsf;jsessionid=
>   -- ID --
>
> ```
> <h3>Seitenauswahl:</h3> -> <li class="currentPage"><span>41</span></li>
> save current page to -> END
> ```

#### Save all Hospital Numbers

```
for(COUNTER = 1; COUNTER <= END; COUNTER++) {
```

> ...Deutsch/5/proxy/dkv/search/results/show/-- COUNTER
>   --/name/asc.jsf;jsessionid= -- ID --

This page contains 10 hospitals each has a number
    select all with:

```
<f:param name="2" value="HOSPITAL NUMBER">
```

This information is, however, within a block Comment, for example:

```
<f:param name="1" value="1" />
<f:param name="2" value="260510995" />
<f:param name="3" value="00" />

}
```

#### Save Hospital Information

```
for each HOSPITAL NUMBER {
...Deutsch/5/proxy/dkv/hospital/show/formular/1.1/-- HOSPITAL NUMBER --/00.jsf
// save to database selected information from
<span id="A-1_id_102_05" // Hospital Name save
<span id="A-1_id_104_07" // Street Name save
<span id="A-1_id_106_09" // House Number save
<span id="A-1_id_108_011" // postal code save
<span id="A-1_id_110_013" // City save
<span id="A-1_id_117_023" // prefix (phone) save
<span id="A-1_id_1171_025" // house connection (phone) save
<span id="A-1_id_1172_027" // direct dialing (phone) save
<span id="A-1_id_119_031" // prefix (fax) save
<span id="A-1_id_1191_033" // house connection (fax) save
<span id="A-1_id_1192_035" // direct dialing (fax) save
<span id="A-1_id_121_039" // e-Mail save
<span id="A-1_id_123_043" // Homepage save
// Any information should have its own column in the Database
}
```

## Export to Excel

I have only rudimentary knowledge in programming and HTML code. 
Can you help me further

Comment: Do you want to perform a page scraping - reading a rendered page for some text?

Comment: No, not quite. 
I want to send a search request to a website. The answer is a restricted list of results. 
These search results I want to go through and store the details in an Excel table. Every detail information I find under another page that I can respond by a specific ID.